# How to count instances of a specific words in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count how many times these ngrams appear in a dataframe's column (df.content) full of articles.
My dataframe is this:

[image]

and my list of ngrams is this:

[image]

The column 'value' in df_ngrams shows how many times a particular ngram appears in df.content but I want to count for every article

I've already tried this:

```
ngrams_count = ['u s', 'president trump', 'donald trump', 'united states', 'white house', 'new york', 'hillary clinton', 'fox news', 'donald trumps', 'president donald']
count = 0
articleCount = 0

for i in df.content:
    articleCount += 1
    for j in ngrams_count:
        if j in i:
            count = i.find(j)
        print ("article ", articleCount, "has ", count, " instances of ngram ", j)
        counts = 0
```

Comment: Is count of every column on every row?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you please rephrase that?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem. The problem is that my for loop doesn't work.You could think of it as a list because it's a huge Dataframe that I can't upload.

Comment: I think you are already there. Import re, then change count = i.find(j) to count=len(re.findall(j, i)).

Comment: You keep mentioning about 'article'. What is this 'article'? Is it a column in the dataframe (which you have not shown in your image above), or is it something else?

Comment: it seems you have your answer, but you could've easily turned this into a [mcve] for us to more easily solve your problem.

Comment: @san Article refers to the content column in df.

Comment: @QuantStats this gives me the same result as the one I already used

Comment: If that is the case, without providing a different approach to tackle this and still utilizing the approach given in the problem, I have just posted a answer below (have not tested though). @KaterinaKass let me know if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df["content"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({el: x.count(el) for el in ngrams_count})).sum()
```

Sample output:

```py
>>> lst
['dfo', 'a', 'd0', 'do']
>>> df
   idx                               cnt
0    1    a fero eo dk v,e oe pero c, el
1    2          fdo pr ck ,,w ld. dp dfp
2    3      40fk ldf mdl sdm dfl mfd dfl
3    4     dov övdke dmc kfdoe flgp dofr
4    5             fdk0v do fdok dlw pds
5    6               dfo df0 ld cödp wpl
6    7              fdo d0 dl dfl dflre
7    8           dfo dfp 0er a na bab sb
8    9           fdo 0fd ldm cd. wdld so
9   10  reo dodf fd0fd dlss0 d0dsl sdl s
>>> df["cnt"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({el: x.count(el) for el in lst})).sum()
dfo    2
a      4
d0     3
do     9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it counts in how many articles I find an ngram. I want to count how many times the ngram appears in every article.                                                  ex. 1. I like pancakes that I made myself                                                                                            
      2. I like travelling as much as I like pancakes                                                           The ngram 'like' is in phrase 1, 1 time and in phrase 2, 2 times

Comment: Nope,it counts exactly how many times given n-gram appears in given article, and then sums it up per n-gram for all articles.

Comment: If you want to have it per article - you can just remove ```.sum()``` from the above

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to provide a different approach, and utilizing your approach, here is the change you need. You need to count the number of occurances of an n_gram, and not jut find it. find() just gives you the index where it is found, and returns -1 if the text couldn't be found (which is not what you want):

```
for i in df.content:
    articleCount += 1
    for j in ngrams_count:
        count = i.count(j)
        print ("article ", articleCount, "has ", count, " instances of ngram ", j)
```